# html unit with android

Tags: android, htmlunit

I have a working code with html unit and java(repeat, working code :P) no errors no missing jars.
now I copy paste this same code into an android project, add the html unit library etc... try to run it and I get 
could not find class "com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.webclient"
and a series of subsequent errors that follow

I tried adding jar files to /libs folder as some suggested(through google) and that cost eclipse to go out of memory before opening the emulator
I also ticking the libraries under order and export (that did not do much)

anyway so the question is, is it possible to get html unit to run with android? and if not, what is the alternative to it in android? my software needs to loginto a server, fill several forms, etc...
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try creating project from existing source ... I have this problem often when I try foreign code.

Comment: I can't since my working project is a java project not an android project. (it says it needs an xml file) I am begining to think html unit is not possible to use with android. Looking for alternatives that are as effective and work with android...

Comment: Joe html is very possible with Android see this tutorial http://marakana.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/selenium2.html

Comment: It seems that selenium opens a browser and auto fills the page? I don't want a browser to open, I want everything to run in the background without the user seeing. which is why HTMLUnit would have been perfect if it wasn't incompatible with android

Comment: Hi Joe I am also in the same need , please inform if u got any result by just post answer here,I will try and let u inform U. :)

Comment: Joe what tutorial or measuring documentation are you using as your base structure?

Comment: Joe if I was in the same position as you "right now" .... I would create a new project and probably start with something like ... this http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html